# I have a copy-paste issue with WordPress

Tags: wordpress

When I paste HTML-code in the WordPress page-editor it inserts several 
tags, but I did not include them in my HTML-code. Does anyone know the cause of this? This is my Original code:

```
<div class="vote_optionality tarn-du">
    <ul>
        <li>1.<input name="" type="radio" value="" />R Squire mall</li>
        <li>2.<input name="" type="radio" value="" />Xylia mall</li>
        <li>3.<input name="" type="radio" value="" />ABC mall</li>
        <li>4.<input name="" type="radio" value="" />can't say</li>>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the result when I paste it in WordPress (on runtime):

```
<div class="vote_optionstxt tran-du">
    <ul>
        <li>1.<br><input name="" type="radio" value="" />R Squere mall<br></li>
        <li>2.<br><input name="" type="radio" value="" />xyz mall<br></li>
        <li>3.<br><input name="" type="radio" value="" />abc mall<br></li>
        <li>4.<br><input name="" type="radio" value="" />can't say<br></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Try my answer and let me know if you still have issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is built in behavior of wordpress editor.
You can stop this behavior using below plugin.
This plugin lets you disable automatic formatting like smart quotes and automatic paragraphs, and use raw HTML/JS/CSS code in your posts without WordPress messing it up.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/

If you dont want to install plugin,
find go to wp-includes/formatting.php file and find below function ,

```
function wpautop($pee, $br = 1)
```

and replace it with

```
function wpautop($pee, $br = 0)
```

Done , Good luck.